# Will a Wireless-G network adapter be able to reap the DISTANCE benefits of a Wireless-N router?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm buying a Wireless-N router for my parent's house for Christmas. They have a rather large house (around 6,000 sq. ft.) so I am going to get them an N router since they will likely need the additional range.

I'm also giving them a laptop which has wireless-G built into it.

My question is this: They don't need the speed benefits of Wireless-N (only DSL is available to them because they live out in the country) but they do need the distance benefits. Would the internal wireless-G NIC in the laptop allow them to reap the distance benefits of the wireless-N router or do I need to puchase a USB wireless-N adapter for them as well?

I haven't been able to find a certain answer on the internet so I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/q/27995/36601) question.

Comment: edited my answer for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't.  Typically the router drops its operating mode to the lowest card on the network.  In the case of a MIMO router, it will use one set of IO operating as G and the others to listen for N connections

Do get the N card.

here's a link: http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3680781/80211n-Delivers-Better-Range.htm

They speculate that G clients got better coverage.  It had to do with not falling back to lower data rates though, not actually achieving longer distances (where there would have been NO connectivity)

Comment: Then I'm glad I asked...thanks for the quality answer!